# Don't understand this collection class syntax

Tags: haskell

```
class Collection c where
  empty :: c key value
  singleton :: key -> value -> c key value
  insert
    :: Ord key
    => key -> value -> c key value -> c key value
  lookup :: Ord key => key -> c key value -> Maybe value
  delete :: Ord key => key -> c key value -> c key value
  keys :: c key value -> [key]
  values :: c key value -> [value]
  toList :: c key value -> [(key, value)]
  fromList :: Ord key => [(key,value)] -> c key value
```

This is unlike what I've read about typeclasses, or the syntax I'm used to. I don't understand what `c key value` represents. Also, what is empty supposed to be? It doesn't resemble a function. Appreciate and am thankful for any help, I'm new to haskell and this is confusing for me

Comment: In English: `Collection` is the set of type constructors of two parameters `c :: Type -> Type -> Type` that have definitions of `empty :: forall key value. c key value`, `singleton :: forall key value. key -> value -> c key value`, and so on. Examples of things that have kind `Type -> Type -> Type` include `(,)`, `Either`, and relevant to this question, `Map` from the `containers` package, e.g. `empty :: Map key value`. Also see `:info Map` and `:kind Map` in GHCi. You might sometimes see the syntax `*` instead of the name `Type`, but nowadays `Type` is preferred—it’s found in `Data.Kind`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type parameter `c` will here not unify with a "concrete" type, but with a type constructor that still expects two parameters.

A simple collection could be:

```
data ListMap a b = ListMap [(a, b)]
```

then we define an instance of `Collection` with:

```
instance Collection ListMap where
    empty = ListMap []

    -- …
```

Indeed, `empty` here has as type `c key value`, so `ListMap key value`, which is then a concrete type.

In this case, a function like `fromList :: Ord key => [(key,value)] -> c key value` will thus result in `fromList :: Ord key => [(key,value)] -> ListMap key value`.

Answer (score 4):

You can infer from how `key` and `value` are used that they must be types (things of kind `*`). Thus, from how `c` is used, you can infer that it must be something of kind `* -> * -> *`: it gets applied to two types to produce another type.

With the `KindSignatures` extension, we can make this more explicit. You could write

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

class Collection (c :: * -> * -> *) where
    empty :: c key value
    -- etc.
```